# TPL Performance With Apache Kafka

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Halo,
I'm unable to get any improved performance with TPL DataFlow and wondering if I'm using it incorrectly.

The application below does the following:

1. Pulls message from a Kafka topic
2. Parses this message into an `Foo` object with `ParseData()`
3. Serializes this `Foo` into JSON
4. Then publishes the JSON to a new Kafka topic.

Some single threaded stats:

- `ParseData` can parse strings into `Foo` at  100 msg/sec (single threaded test)
- `SerializeMessage` can do 200 `Foos`/sec (single threaded test)
- Consuming Kafka messages (skipping all the parsing/serializing) can handle over **2000 msgs/sec**

Based on this, I had hopes to leverage TPL for improving throughput.  My max throughput should be close to the Kafka limit of 2000 msgs/sec.

However, I'm not seeing any improvements in throughput and I'm running the application on a machine with 12 physical cores (24 w HT).  When I print out the size of the queue for each block, the `transformBlock` is always around 1000, but the others are under 10 which leads me to believe that the transformBlock isn't leveraging multi-core system.

Have I setup TPL DataFlow to leverage paralellism correctly?

```cs
app = new App();
await app.Start(new[]{"consume-topic"}, cancelSource);


// App class
async Task Start(IEnumerable<string> topics, CancellationTokenSource cancelSource) {
    transformBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Foo>(TransformKafkaMessage,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8,
            BoundedCapacity = 1000,
            SingleProducerConstrained = true,
        });
    serializeBlock = new TransformBlock<Foo, string>(SerializeMessage,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
            BoundedCapacity = 1000,
            SingleProducerConstrained = true,
        });
   publishBlock = new ActionBlock<JsonMessage>(PublishJson,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
            BoundedCapacity = 1000,
            SingleProducerConstrained = true
        }); 

    // Setup the pipeline
    transformBlock.LinkTo(serializeBlock);
    serializeBlock.LinkTo(publishBlock);

    // Start Kafka Listener loop
    consumer.Subscribe(topics);
    while(true) {
        var result = consumer.Consume(cancelSource.Token);
        await ProcessMessage<Ignore, string>(result);
    }
}

// send the content of the kafka message to transform block
async Task ProcessMessage<TKey, TValue>(ConsumeResult<TKey, string> msg) {
    var result = await transformBlock.SendAsync(msg.Value);
}

// Convert the raw string data into an object
Foo TransformKafkaMessage(string data) {
    // Note this ParseData() function can process about 100 items per sec
    // in local single threaded testing
    Foo foo = ParseData(data);
    return foo;
}

// Serialize the new Foo into JSON
string SerializeMessage(Foo foo) {
    // The serializer can process about 200 msgs/sec (single threaded test)
    var json = foo.Serialize();
    return json;
}

// publish new message back to Kafka
void PublishJson(string json) {
    // Create a Confluent.Kafka Message
    var kafkaMessage = new Message<Null, string> {
        Value = json
    };
    producer.Produce("produce-topic", kafkaMessage);
}
```

Comment: According to your tests `SerializeMessage` has twice the throughput of `TransformKafkaMessage`, and you have set `MaxDegreeOfPrallelism=8` for first transform block, so it's possible that it produces 8 messages concurrently, but due to double throughput of `SerializeMessage` block it never goes above 10 in it's internal queue. What kind of improvement do you expect that you're not seeing ?

Comment: If I set each block `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` I see an overall throughput for about ~100 msgs/sec due to `ParseData()` throughput (expected this).  If I increase `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8` on the transform and/or serialization blocks, I expected significant throughput improvement (perhaps 300-500 msg/sec overall), but still see overall throughput of 100-120 msgs/sec.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't `ParseData`? Does it use any global data, locking, synchronization? Have you checked Task Manager to see what the cores do, how much RAM is used? You may be losing time to allocations and garbage collection

Comment: Open the [Diagnostics Tools window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) during debugging to see what's going on with RAM and CPU. An inefficient parser can easily end up allocating hundreds of MB for just a few MB of source. A parse tree may be several times larger than the source data simply because it contains all of that data broken up in multiple objects.

Comment: In a similar situation I used ANTLR to parse a multi-MB text file that contained records of about 20 lines each. The naive approach, using a full parse tree and a Visitor ended up using several hundreds of MB and was extremely slow due to allocations and GCs. Using listeners and trimming the tree after each record was parsed resulted in 10x better performance and only a few MBs of RAM.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you are correct.  `ParseData` is parsing the data into a DTO with about 1000 events and each event has about 35 string properties.  I'm using XmlReader to parse the data into a DTO, but I guess all of those string allocations are slowing everything down.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you put your comments into an answer I will accept.  I will also appreciate any additional reference or pointers you found helpful when using ANTLR.  I'm not sure how I can avoid allocating all of these string into a DTO that can then be serialized back into JSON.